# React JS + google tag manager: how to get data layer triggered on page transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I received problems when trying to send data to GTM (google tag manager) in a React application. We already managed to put different scripts on the related page(s).

For example below is one of script we put in cart page:

```
class Cart extends Component {

  render() {
    const { cartItems } = this.props;
    return (
      <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'viewCart',
            cartItems: ${cartItems}
          });
          window.history = window.history || [];
          window.history.pushState({
            page: 'Current Cart Page',
            events: 'viewCart',
            cartItems: ${cartItems},
          }, 'Current Cart Page');
        ` }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The above script will not executed when we access to cart page from another page (E.G.: home page), but when we refresh the page, it gets triggered.

It turns out that the data layer only pushed on `pageLoad` and `DOMReady` event. but not in `historyChange`

Has anyone encountered this before and know how to solve it?